# Pandas. Trying to delete rows on condition but code replaces column with another column

Tags: python, pandas

So in the beginning I get a look over my db.

```
print(sales.head)
print(sales['SALE PRICE'].describe())
```

After that I use a trick to keep rows that don't contain this kind of NULL value

```
sales['SALE PRICE'] = sales[sales['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']
```

After that I check if everything is done wright

```
print(sales.head)
print(sales['SALE PRICE'].describe())
```

But my program just replaces SALE PRICE column with 0th column that contains indexes
Any ideas?

Comment: do you mean `sales = sales[sales['SALE PRICE'] != ' -   '`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to assign result back to `sales` instead of column.

```
sales = sales[sales['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']
```

- `sales['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  '` This will return Indexes with `True` and `False` Values.
- So `sales[sales['SALE PRICE'] != ' -  ']` This already returns a DataFrame you wants.